# Zend Framework2におけるPHPのプロパティ

Tags: php, zend-framework

いつも勉強させていただいております。
現在Zend Framework2を利用してPHPの勉強をしている学生です。
もしよければ質問させてください。

画面Aから画面Bへ移動する際、画面Aで利用した値をBでも利用したいと思い、クラスにプロパティを定義してそこに入れるようにしました。($this->propertyのように)

しかし画面Aで入れた値が画面Bでは消えてしまっていました…。GETやPOSTで次の画面へ渡すことはできたのですが、PHPではプロパティに入れて保持しておくことはできないのでしょうか？コンストラクタが画面遷移毎にコールされていたので毎回初期化されているのかもしれませんが。。。
もしそうだとしたらプロパティはどういう使い方をするためにあるのでしょうか？
プロパティの使い方や画面をまたいだ値の保持の仕方についてご教授いただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: プロパティが画面を超えて保持されることを期待されていたということは、そのような言語・フレームワークをお使いだったのでしょうか。そちらの名前も挙げていただけると、対比して説明することができるかと思います。

Comment: unarist様
コメントありがとうございます！
PHPではないのですが、C++やObjectiveCを利用したことがありまして、そちらではメンバ変数の値がインスタンスがある間はずっと残っていました。その感覚でPHPを使っていましたのでプロパティが消えてしまうことに違和感があります…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` と言われているのが ZendFramework2 のコントローラクラスなら、仰るように、リクエストを受け付けるたびに新しいインスタンスが生成されます。そのプロパティはあくまで「1リクエストを処理する間、データを保持しておくもの」とお考えください。

> PHPではないのですが、C++やObjectiveCを利用したことがありまして、そちらではメンバ変数の値がインスタンスがある間はずっと残っていました。

「インスタンスがある間は」というのが重要です。デスクトップアプリケーションの場合は最長で「アプリを起動してから終了するまで」残り続けるわけですが、Webアプリケーションの場合、そもそも「起動してから終了するまで」という考え方が少し異なります。

言語や構成にもよりますが、Webアプリケーションでは次のような流れが多いです。

1. Webサーバーがリクエストを受け取る
2. **プログラムを起動し**、リクエストを渡す
3. プログラムは処理を行った結果をWebサーバーに渡して**終了する**
4. Webサーバーが3の結果をレスポンスとして送り返す

この場合、リクエストごとにプログラムが終了してしまうため、プログラム内の変数やインスタンスが各リクエストを越えて生存することは不可能です。

ではリクエストを越えてデータを保持したい場合はどうするのかというがセッション管理です。基本的なのが Cookie です。レスポンスで設定したCookieはブラウザで保持され、その後のリクエストで一緒に送信してもらえます。

ただこれは格納可能な量が少ないですし、なんとなればユーザーが自由に閲覧・編集できてしまうので安全な場所ではありません。そういう時には Cookie 上にはセッションIDと呼ばれる識別子だけを残し、その実態はサーバー側のファイルやDBに格納する、という方法を取ります。

[「セッション管理」のすべて - ステップ1 ［基本のしくみ］：ITpro](http://itpro.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/COLUMN/20081010/316687/)

PHP自身にもセッションを扱う仕組みは用意されていますが、ZF2を通して使うとよいでしょう。この場合 `Zend\Session\Container` というクラスを使うようです。

[ZendFramework2の入門から極意まで徹底解説 | ZendFramework2ガイド](http://zf2.t-pg.net/basic/controller#16)

Comment: unarist様
ご回答ありがとうございます！一人で学習している状態なのでとても助かりました。そもそもの考え方が違っていたと気づけました。

よろしければもう少々質問させてください・・・
セッションを使ってデータを保持することができるのであれば、PHPのクラスのプロパティはどういう状況で使うのでしょうか？1回のリクエストでクラス内の関数を複数コールするときに使うくらいなのかなと思いますが、あってますか？
また、ご回答いただくまえにいじくりまわしていたところ、forwardしたときはプロパティの値が残っていました。私のほうで少々調べたところ、forwardはユーザからリクエストを受けてそれをそのまま別の処理に回すため、起動としては一回ということであってるでしょうか？
質問ばかりで申し訳ありませんが、ご教授ください・・・

Comment: どちらもあってます。forwardは別のアクションを実行することができますが、これはZendFramework内での流れを変えるだけですから、ブラウザから見れば一回のリクエストです。似た用語にredirectというものがありますが、これは別のURLを参照するようブラウザに指示しますから、二回のリクエストです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！理解がとても進みました。親切に教えていただきとてもうれしかったです。また質問させていただくかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。